# how to iterate multiple lists in django template

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates

I'm trying to iterate my nested dictionary on template but it don't iterate cards but it return a list like this  (first example image) instead of iterating cards.

[image]
but want iterate three list like second image(second example image)
[image]
That said, if each card has associated posts, and each post associated (lists of) content,

So here is my Nested dictionary

```
cards = [
{'card_title': card_postings,
  'posts': [
      {'post_title': arrays,
        'contents': post_content,}
  ],
},
]
```

And also this is template

```
      {% for card in cards %}
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="text-center">{{ card.card_title }}</h4>
                    <div class="row row-cols-1 row-cols-sm-2 row-cols-md-3 g-3">
                      {% for post in cards.posts %} 
                        <div class="col">
                        <div class="card">
                            <div class="card-header text-center text-primary">
                              <h5>{{ post.post_title }}</h5>
                            </div>
                            <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                              <li class="list-group-item border-0">
                                {% for content in post.contents %}
                                <i>{{ content }} <br> </i> 
                                {% endfor %}
                              </li>
                            </ul>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
      {% endfor %}
```

By the way all of these variables (card_postings,arrays,post_content) in nested dictionary are lists

Comment: ....and what's the question?  nested for loops are permitted IIRC

Comment: @2e0byo this iterate only card_postings and arrays lists.But I want to iterate post_content list also

Comment: @2e0byo this iterate only card_postings and arrays lists.But I want to iterate post_content list inside of arrays list.Example like arrays iterate inside of zipped_lists

Comment: I think you might be confused about what zip does.  zip will take the top entry and return that.  But you haven't provided you lists: we need to see the input data

Comment: @2e0byo those lists are really big and it's are dynamic.Because I scrape it from site using beautifulsoup anyway if you wanna my look up here is source code for that [github](https://github.com/dtheekshanalinux/django-french-conjugator)

Comment: `cards = [
    {'card_title': card_postings,
      'posts': [
          {'post_title': arrays,
            'contents': post_content,}
      ],
    },
    ]` One person told me that create a nested dictionay like this.But it also didn't work   either.So do you have any suggestion

Comment: right, so `zip()` is getting you only *one* element in each list.  Try printing `list(zipped_list)`.  (And add the output---truncated to the first few elements---here).  Also add your calling code directly in the question: we haven't got time to go all over github making sense of it.  Make life easy! :)

Comment: @2e0byo Now check the question I updated question with a nested dictionay and required loops for nested dictionary